# Django JWT authentication with PUT request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am trying to update the first_name field for a user using a JWT token for authentication, for some reason when I am doing it in a different table where there is no username and password field ,I can easily do it and update the details using JWT token. 
But when i do it in Django user model default table,it keep asking me to include the username and password on the request(even thought I don't want to update them). here is the error I am getting when sending the request using postman

```
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

even though I have the authorisation header set right and it works with any other request, but not when updating user details, I have included all the necessary and default authentication classes. any help is appreciated, been trying to solve this small thing for 4 days now.

curl command not working

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT <token>" -X PUT  http://localhost:8000/user/3/ -d '{"first_name":"curl_test"}'
```

curl command working

```
curl -H "Authorization: JWT <token>" -X GET  http://localhost:8000/user/3/
```

NOTICE THE DIFFERENT method.
my views.py (UserDetails class)

```
class UserDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsOwner, IsAuthenticated)
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a user instance.
    """

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404


    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            user = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
            user.profile.updated = timezone.now()
            user.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',

    )
}
```

JWT is fully working ,when sending an old Token on the request I am getting Signature expired, but when I put the latest token I get the username/passwords are required fields.

Comment: try to use `patch` method

Comment: Same error. JWT says i have to include the username and password and ignoring the token on the header

Comment: add json of the data you send to the server,

Comment: You want me to include the curl command i sent? I will do that once my laptop finishes updating

Comment: yes add it to your question, please

Comment: Looks like you are sending request to the endpoint which expects to receive username and password in JSON. Advice about `PATCH` request sounds promising. But if it will not work — check if DRF/JWT are configured properly. Forgotten (not included) middleware or authentication backend can be a reason too.

Comment: I think I have stressed it out few times now. any GET request with the JWT header WORKS, any PUT request (on a different table "transaction" for example) WORKS.the conflict happens when I try to  PUT request and update the first name of a user, it will ask for username and completely ignores the HEADER, please explain how it is a authentication backend, I have only used the default classes.

Comment: I have tried with PATCH method, I am getting the same error as PUT request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user serializer is enforcing all fields data, use `partial=True` to allow [partial updates](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates):

```
serializer = UserSerializer(user, data={'username': u'test'}, partial=True)
```

Comment: I will give it a try once i finish updating my laptop

Comment: I just tried it, the issue is not partial update or a fully one, I have the same exact code on a different table where there are no username/passwords fields and using PUT request on it is fine with JWT. the issue seems to be with rest-framework-jwt it wants the username and password even though the token header is included. Obtain/Verify/refresh token works with no problems.

Comment: How do you know that the error returned is from JWT and not `UserSerializer`? Stacktrace?